# Expected number of coin changeovers when considering the possible changeover from the nth throw to the 1st throw

Tags: probability

I am having trouble figuring this out with certainty. As far as I know the expected value for the number of changeovers when throwing a fair coin n times is

(n-1)/2

and it is worked out by defining n-1 different indicator variables for the possible changeover from the ith throw to the (i+1)th throw and then treating it as a binomial distribution. Is this correct? If it is, then when we extend the problem such that now we have to consider the possible changeover from the nth throw to the 1st throw (as if thrown in a circle?), would anything change? What would be the the expected value for the number of changeovers then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem is equivalent to that of tossing a fair coin $n-1$ times and asking for the expected number of heads: each toss after the first corresponds to a head if it’s a changeover and a tail if it is not. The expected number of heads in $n-1$ tosses is indeed $\frac{n-1}2$.

The extended problem is equivalent to that of tossing a fair coin $n$ times, since its last toss is independent of its first toss.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense but is the calculation the same? I mean, can we still treat it as a binomial distribution? Wouldn't the possible changeover from the nth throw to the first throw have a different probability than the others?

Comment: The derived $Y_i=X_i\oplus X_{i+1\bmod2}$ flips are not iid, but $E\sum Y_i = n/2$ by linearity of expectation.

Comment: Why exactly wouldn't they be independent? Is it because of this last changeover or because of something else?

Comment: @AlexH: I was mostly trying to give you some intuition for the problem; **kimchi lover** has given a more technical explanation. Here _iid_ means _independent identically distributed_. The $\mod 2$ means that the $0-1$ variables $X_i$ and $X_{i+1}$ are added modulo $2$, so that $1\oplus 1=0$ (no changeover). To see that the $Y_i$ are not mutually independent, consider $n=3$ for simplicity: if you know the values of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, you can deduce the value of $Y_3$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @AlexH: You’re welcome!